# Installing the Ubuntu Server in Ubuntu

Tags: server

My first Question is 
Q - 1) How to Install Ubuntu Server 13.10 in Ubuntu 13.10?

Q - 2) What are the uses of this server and where can we find a manual wherein we can get a complete detail regarding the use of this server with some example?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

The way you can install server 13.10 inside 13.10, is by use of a virtual machine.  You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page), or [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) which both are free, or use [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/), which is a paid app.

As far as what do you use a server for, is really an open ended question, but to get a very good idea about Ubuntu server, and what you can use it for, you may want to check out the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf).

Comment: Firstly I would like to thank you still what I mean is as follows :- 
-> I had Installed Ubuntu 13.10 in VMware and I am having an ISO of Ubuntu server 13.10 so how can I Install that server in my already Installed ubuntu 13.10. What steps should I follow in order to Install that server in my already installed Ubuntu.

Comment: You mean Ubuntu 13.10 is already installed inside a VM?  If it is, what is the host OS?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu is already Installed in my VM Ware and My host OS is Windows 8.